# Developing themes for Xperia Z

Tags: sony, sony-xperia

I want to create themes for Xperia Z devices, just like the ones which show up in the personalisation section of the device. How can I start building them?

Answer (score 0):

There are apps inside Google Play that can be used to create your own personal theme.

Try "GO Launcher Theme Maker", if you didn't like that, then you can find your own theme maker by searching for "xperia z theme creator" or "xperia z theme maker."

Answer (score 0):

If you have not rooted your phone, stop reading.

If you have rooted your phone, I found on XDA this theme creator (Windows or linux): http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1826413